# Comment choisir entre les sujets impersonnels « ça » et « il » ?

Tags: pronoms, pronoms-impersonnels

En voulant dire « ça suffit ! » à mon chat, je me suis rappelé que la variante « il suffit » était aussi correcte, même si peut-être tombée en désuétude.

Dans quels cas doit-on, ou peut-on, choisir « ça », et dans quels cas doit-on choisir « il » ? Existe-t-il un ensemble de règles à ce sujet ?

Voici quelques exemples qui me viennent en tête :

> Il suffit !
>   Il suffisait d'y penser.
>   Il pleut.
>   Il va faire noir.

Contre :

> Ça suffit !
>   Ça ne mange pas de pain.
>   Ça craint.
>   Ça va barder.
>   Ça dépend.
>   Ça tombe dru.

Comment: De mémoire, sauf dans certaines expressions figées ils sont interchangeables.

Comment: Il m'étonnerait beaucoup.

Comment: Dans tous les exemples avec "_ça_", le pronom renvoie à la situation. Alors que dans les exemples avec "_il_", le pronom me donne l'impression de ne pas renvoyer vers quoi que ce soit.

Comment: Cha(t) suffit !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rule of thumb: *ça* quand il s'agit de quelque chose en particulier, *il* quand il s'agit d'un état ou d'une situation générale

- *Ça suffit !*
- *Ça ne mange pas de pain*
- *Ça craint*
- *Ça va barder*
- *Ça dépend*
- *Ça tombe dru*.

Font tous référence à quelque chose de précis, ou à la situation très locale ("ça va barder", ici, précisément, c'est pas une généralité pour toute la zone)

- *Il suffit !*
- *Il suffisait d'y penser*
- *Il pleut*
- *Il va faire noir*

Font plutôt référence à un état général, ou à quelque chose s'appliquant à une étendue large.

Par exemple :
*ça suffit* fait référence à quelque chose de précis (une conversation en cours, ou une action), alors que *il suffit* fait référence à tout (et demande en général un arrêt global de tout ce qui se passe alentour, d'où le côté plus pédant, supérieur, ce pour quoi il est rarement utilisé)

*il pleut* fait référence au fait qu'il pleut sur une étendue assez large (normalement..), alors que *ça tombe dru* fait référence au fait que là, devant soi, on peut observer qu'il pleut fort

Après, cela reste une règle de base, et il y a **toujours** des exceptions, mais ça reste assez valable.

Comment: On peut ajouter que la forme impersonnelle se construit avec "il" normalement (qui ne fait référence à rien, au contraire de ça).

Answer (score 6):

De façon générale:

- *il* est un pronom personnel ; *il* est toujours sujet
- *cela* désigne une chose ou une idée ; *ça* peut être sujet ou COD

## Locutions

Dans les locutions, ils sont souvent interchangeables, et *il* est plus littéraire que *ça*.

Pour les usages exclusifs de l'un ou l'autre, voir leurs définitions respectives ([il](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/il) [ça](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A7a))

### locutions impersonnelles avec *être*

avec *être* ou un verbe d'état suivi d'un adjectif ou d'un substantif

> il est très tard, il est midi, il est l'heure de dîner

est plus littéraire que

> c'est midi, c'est l'heure de manger

### concurrence dans certaines locutions

> il suffit; tu réponds c'est assez! (Lamart., Harm., 1830, p. 292)

est plus littéraire que

> ça suffit

### *il* s'emploie pour les phénomènes naturels

> il neige

*ça* s'emploie moins couramment, et dans un style populaire

> *ça neige*

Comment: Il y a beaucoup d'inexactitudes dans cette réponse ! Voir la réponse de Cristol.